# How do I cast a Java Object into a List of integers?

Tags: java, list, casting

A method of some poorly documented library is returning me a List of Objects. I know that the list contains ArrayLists of integers. As follows:

```
List<?> result = lib.get();
Iterator<?> iterator = result.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Object next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(next.toString());
    System.out.println(next.getClass());
}
```

Gets me

```
 [0, 0] 
 class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList 
 [0, 1] 
 class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList 
 [0, 2] 
 class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

How can I get to turn those objects into ArrayList so that I can use them properly?

Comment: Cast it and ignore the warning?

Comment: Looks like you have a list of arrays of integers, not a list of Integers.

Comment: @BasilBourque can't be a list of array of integers, since the toString for integer arrays doesn't print out its contents. Perhaps list of list of integers

Comment: @ShashwatKhanna, the output shows that it's a collection of arrays wrapped by calling `java.util.Arrays.asList(...)`. Not that it's of any particular use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only cast the **Object next = ...** object into the type **java.util.Arrays$ArrayList**, but because it is a private static class, it is better to cast it to **java.util.List** class.

Like:

```
List<?> result = lib.get();
Iterator<?> iterator = result.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Object next = iterator.next();
    // -------------------
    List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) next;
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(list.get(1));
    // -------------------
}
```

Comment: It works by casting it as `(List<Integer>)`. If I cast it as an ArrayList it raises the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: @ZzKr you just need to import the correct `ArrayList` I guess.

Comment: @ZzKr yes. **java.util.Arrays$ArrayList** is a private static class in **java.util.Arrays**. Because it implemented the **java.util.List** interface then you can cast it to List.

Comment: No need to cast each individual sub-list, you can cast the entire thing once and be done with it, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296641/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You cannot cast the entire thing, as it is a `List` of `List` objects that hold `Integer` objects (apparently). So loop the outer list, and cast each element `List` object to be a `List< Integer >` object.

## List of lists of integers

You appear to have a list of lists of integers, not a list of integers.

```
    List < Object > objects = new ArrayList <> ( 3 );
    objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 0 ) );
    objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 1 ) );
    objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 2 ) );

    System.out.println ( objects );
```

> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]

Unfortunately, you cannot simply cast to a concrete type as suggested in [the other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296323/642706) because we do not know the concrete type. We can presume that we have a `List`, but not a `ArrayList`.

See this example. The `List.of` method generates an object of an unspecified class that implements `List`. We can see here that whatever concrete class is used, it is not `ArrayList`.

```
    List < Object > objects = new ArrayList <> ( 3 );
    objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 0 ) );
    objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 1 ) );
    objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 2 ) );

    System.out.println ( objects );

    Iterator < ? > iterator = objects.iterator ();
    while ( iterator.hasNext () )
    {
        Object next = iterator.next ();
        List < Integer > list = ( ArrayList < Integer > ) next;
        System.out.println ( list.get ( 0 ) );
        System.out.println ( list.get ( 1 ) );
    }
```

…throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList (java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12 and java.util.ArrayList are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

We can cast each element to a `List< Integer >`.

```
List < Object > objects = new ArrayList <> ( 3 );
objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 0 ) );
objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 1 ) );
objects.add ( List.of ( 0 , 2 ) );

System.out.println ( objects );

Iterator < ? > iterator = objects.iterator ();
while ( iterator.hasNext () )
{
    Object next = iterator.next ();
    List < Integer > list = ( List < Integer > ) next;
    System.out.println ( list.get ( 0 ) );
    System.out.println ( list.get ( 1 ) );
}
```

When run.

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
0
0
0
1
0
2
```

I do not know of a way to directly cast the original list. This next line gives a compiler error of `inconvertible types`.

```
List < List < Integer > > listOfListOfIntegers = ( List < List < Integer > > ) objects;
```

Comment: Ihr looks like the lists in OP's question were created by `Arrays.asList()`, not `List.of()`. You should be able to cast to `Arrays`' inner class `ArrayList` (although I'm not sure why you would want to).

Comment: @daniu Yes, I suppose you could make that assumption. But it would be a hack. But the publisher of the data would be free to change to another implementation of `List` at any time, breaking your code. I would not bother unless there were some reason working with `List` the interface proved insufficient.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the point about casting to concrete class. I updated my answer.

Comment: No need to cast each individual sub-list, and no need to cast to actual list type, assuming that you're only going to read the values anyway, not update the lists. You *can* cast the entire thing, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296641/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of lists of integers, you can simply do

```
List<List<Integer>> newList = result.stream()
                             .map(e->(List<Integer>)e)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the value returned by `lib.get()` to `List<List<Integer>>`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<List<Integer>> result = (List<List<Integer>>) lib.get();
```

*Proof*

```
// Simulate lib.get() and prove that it is same as question code
List<?> result = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(0, 0),
                               Arrays.asList(0, 1),
                               Arrays.asList(0, 2));
for (Object next : result) {
    System.out.println(next);
    System.out.println(next.getClass());
}

// Fix it
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<List<Integer>> fixedResult = (List<List<Integer>>) result;

// Print the fixed result
for (List<Integer> list : fixedResult) {
    for (int value : list)
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
[0, 0]
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
[0, 1]
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
[0, 2]
class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
0 0 
0 1 
0 2
```

Comment: Compiler error: `List::get` requires an `int` argument. "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: @BasilBourque I just copy/pasted that code back into my Eclipse and compiled and executed it on both Java 8 and Java 11. I also compiled and executed from command-line. No compiler errors, and output is as shown.